# WP_Query returns posts_per_page + 1 every time

Tags: wp-query

I have a simple `WP_Query` where I am intending to only get the latest 4 posts returned:

```
<?php
      $query = new WP_Query([
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'orderby' => 'date',
      'order' => 'DESC',
      'posts_per_page' => 4,
    ]);

    var_dump(count($query->posts));die;    // Returns 5 instead of 4
?>
```

`count($query->posts)` is 5 every time. Why isn't it 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this happen when you have sticky posts. Try excluding them, like this:

```
<?php
      $query = new WP_Query([
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'orderby' => 'date',
          'order' => 'DESC',
          'posts_per_page' => 4,
          'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    ]);
?>
```